# Spring mvc import simple html

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc. Now, I am trying to put inside my JSPs simple import to HTML file which contains the toolbar.

This tag does not seem to be working:

```java
<jsp:include page="toolbar.html" />
```

I tried to put it in the root of the webapp folder (changed the path of the import of course),
but still.. it did not work.

How do I do this?

Comment: In which directory are toolbar.html and the jsp where you are doing the jsp:include ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

I had to add a method in the controller, since I used the jsp tag. 
It seems that the path was right but the jsp resource was never connected.

Thanks